# Blazor with OIDC (AAD), how to log out?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I have Blazor server app on .NET 7, using Azure AD authentication, with typical "tutorial" setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {        
        configuration.Bind(configSectionName, options);        
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

It works fine. But how do I correctly sign out user?

If I use `<a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>` and click it, it will just navigate to `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut` and say `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.`

Isn't the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` call supposed to setup some handler for these URLs and handle sign-out correctly (call logout endpoint on AAD, etc)? Am I missing some configuration in order for this to happen?

EDIT: My configuration section from appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomain.com",
  "TenantId": "263639d4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ClientId": "06176f4f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ClientSecret": "rSAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

If I open chrome developer tools, normally when I click on links, nothing appears in network log (which I understand to be normal, websocket connection is used), but when I click sign out link, there seems to be full page load - HTML, css, javascripts, websocket connect...

Comment: Iam able to Logout Successfully without any issues.[LogOut](https://i.imgur.com/pRUPiHO.png)

Comment: Could you please share your Configuration file.

Comment: Hi @rouen,  I also have test in my local, and can't reproduce the issue. Now I want to check the network information inside the browser developer tools, and what the http request being sent when click the `log out` link.

Comment: @rouen - Change `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>` code to `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))` and check once.

Comment: Hi @Harshitha I think it nothing to do with the settings, I have checked it.  `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
`

Comment: @Harshitha Because op can log in successfully, right ?

Comment: Yes.... @Jason Pan. Even Iam able to work with his code.

Comment: @Harshitha So we need to check the network trace when click the a tag.

Comment: Hey guys, see my edit of the post.

Comment: @rouen - Yes, even I have the same setting and an additional `MicrosoftGraph` and `DownstreamApi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, here is what I found.

With my configuration, it is expected for `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut` endpoint to NOT exists. These endpoints are handled by `AccountController` ([source](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs)) which is added by `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` which I don't have (or need - my app has no user management UI; every user in AAD tenant can access it, and noone else).

So I looked into source code of components implementing sign out for OIDC (mainly `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` and `OpenIdConnectHandler`) and this is basically how you can do Microsoft AD sign out in Blazor server without all the UI overhead:

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @context.User.Identity?.Name
        <a href="@logoutRedirectUri"><span class="oi oi-account-logout" title="Log out"></span></a>
    </Authorized>    
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    string logoutRedirectUri = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        var loginHint = request.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("login_hint");

        logoutRedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri="
            + Uri.EscapeDataString(request.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + request.Host + request.PathBase + "/signout-oidc");

        if (loginHint != null)
        {
            logoutRedirectUri += "&logout_hint=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(loginHint);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add `"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc"` to your configuration (right along with `"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"`) AND you need to add this URL to redirect URLs in your app registration in Azure portal (where you have `/signin-oidc` URLs).

The `logout_hint` is optional and what it does is, that in case you are logged into into multiple MS accounts, `logout_hint` can skip the step where you must pick the one you want to logout from. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc).